# How to stop wrapfigure floating in rmarkdown to pdf

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I have a RMarkdown document with some text, and I want to wrap the text around a figure. Now this hasn't been a problem previously using **wrapfigure**, however all of a sudden the image floats to the bottom of the document no matter what I try to do!

MWE that doesn't work for me:

```
---
title: "TEST"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
lang: "en"
output:
  pdf_document
fontsize: 10pt
header-includes:
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
- \usepackage{lipsum}
- \usepackage{mwe}
urlcolor: blue
---

\begin{wrapfigure}[H]{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}

# Header 1
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
```

[image: Here is a link to the result. I cannot attach images yet :/]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that rmarkdown automatically loads the babel package with the `bidi=default` option as soon as any `lang` is specified in the header -- even if the language is English and definitely not written in any direction but from left to right. The `bidi` option makes zero sense in this case and will just cause trouble.

To avoid this, I suggest to remove the `lang` field in your header. The advantages of loading `babel` in an English document aren't terrible big (all the things like figure and table names are in English by default) and this avoids the problem with `wrapfig`...

(There is also a tiny syntax error in `\begin{wrapfigure}[H]{r}{0.5\textwidth}` -> The `H` is wrong, replace it by the number of lines the wrapfigure should span or leave it empty for wrapfig trying to guess the correct number automatically)

```
---
title: "TEST"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
fontsize: 10pt
header-includes:
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
- \usepackage{lipsum}
- \usepackage{mwe}
urlcolor: blue
---
# Header 1

\begin{wrapfigure}[]{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
```

[image]

Comment: Removing the "lang" argument in the YAML header worked! Thanks!